# Is there conflict between the law of excluded middle and "no set is its own member"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

And if yes, then how can it be resolved?

As far as I know in standard set theory it's true that "no set is its own member".
Also in standard logic the law of excluded middle is true, either $A$ or $\lnot A$.

Now let's consider simple sentence "Entity $X$ is either a real number or not a real number".
This can be restated in terms of set theory as "Element $x$ either belongs to set $\mathbb{R}$ or
to set non-$\mathbb{R}$".

Looks like a tautology, doesn't it? But I will show you that it's not because there is one 
thing that isn't a member of either set. Namely, it's set "non-$\mathbb{R}$". This can't belong to
set $\mathbb{R}$ because it isn't a real number. This also can't belong to set non-$\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. it can't belong
to itself) because of "no set is its own member". Thus "Element $x$ either belongs to set $\mathbb{R}$ or to set non-$\mathbb{R}$" isn't a tautology.

Comment: I suspect the answer is something like "there is no such thing as the set non-$\mathbb R$". A similar idea is that there is no "set of all things", because it would have to contain itself. Trying to introduce a set of all things that are not real numbers is similar to trying to introduce a set of all things.

Comment: Your example absolutely does not work. The proper translation is "$x\in \mathbb R$ or $\neg x\in \mathbb R$". What you wrote literally makes no sense.

Comment: You have an implicit assumption that there is a universal set. Assuming ZF(C), there is none.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does it mean that there are no absolute complements in ZFC?

Comment: @GitGud: I'm pretty sure "non-R" is intended to mean, in class builder notation, $\{ x \mid x \notin \mathbb{R} \}$

Comment: @Hurkyl Me too. I stand by my statement: "$x$ is a real number or $x$ is not a real number" translates to "$x\in \mathbb R$ or $\neg x\in \mathbb R$", it's just the definition of "$x$ is a real number" coupled with *negation*.

Comment: @GitGud Then how can we specify set that contains every element that isn't a real number except itself?

Comment: @user161005 "$x$ is something other than a real number". The concept of "not being *something*" isn't the same as "being something other than *something*".

Comment: @GitGud I hoped for symbolic notation ...

Comment: The move from $\lnot (x \in \mathbb R)$ to $(x \notin \mathbb R)$ is safe: it is only "logic". But the next move, to $(x \in \mathbb R^C)$ assume that the set $\mathbb R^C$ exists. It needs mathematics, i.e. it needs the proof in the relevant part of math (i.e. set theory) that the existence of the purported set is provable from set axioms.

Comment: @user161005 Then it is as Hurkyl suggested, but I'm taking issue with the way you go from English to symbolic notation. Even if you were to use Hurkyl's notation, I'd still have a problem with going from your statement in English to that symbolic notation.
And this isn't just pedantry. It's very possible that the moment you properly write (or conceptualize) stuff in English, then the issues dissipate.

Comment: @GitGud Okay, let's try from scratch. "Set non-R contains all elements of universe except members of set R and set non-R itself. By "universe" I mean set that contains all existing elements **except** itself".

Comment: @user161005 You cannot specify such a set because (as you proved in your post) it does not exist. However you can specify everything that is not a real number by the predicate $x\not\in\Bbb R$. Just not every predicate gives you a set.

Comment: @M.Winter "Just not every predicate gives you a set. " Does it mean that we can't use set theory to model whole logic of predicates?

Comment: @user161005 What do you mean with "modeling logic of predicates"? If for every predicate you want to have the "collection" of sets that satisfy this predicate, then I recommend you to look into NBG set theory with proper classes.

Comment: @user161005 Exactly what M. Winter said: you cannot specify such a set. And the issue disappears.

Comment: And let me answer the unanswered question you raised in the comments. Yes, ZFC set theory eschews the notion of universal sets, and along with that the notion of absolute complements. The situation is not improved by going to MK set theory, which has two types of objects, sets and classes of sets, because although every class of set has a complement with respect to the class of all sets, again there cannot be any class of all classes without Russell's paradox striking again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is similar to [Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox).

The usual approach is to cast blame on the principle of *unrestricted comprehension* — the hypothesis that for any property $P$ of sets, there is a set of everything satisfying $P$.

ZFC replaces this with the more modest hypothesis that if you're additionally given a set $S$, then you can form the set of everything in $S$ satisfying $P$.

In particular, in the usual formulation of modern set theory, the thing you call "non-R" is not a set. (c.f. "proper class")

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83270/discussion-on-answer-by-hurkyl-is-there-conflict-between-the-law-of-excluded-mid).